# Book series: last dragon, transformed to a human by a wizard, falls in love with an elf

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I remember the book (series) starting off with the slaying of an ice dragon, which is the second to last dragon left. The actual last dragon is friends with a wizard, who turns the dragon into a scrawny teenage boy to protect him since he was going to recklessly attack the dragon slayer squad.

They come across a massacre of some sort in the forest, meet a female elf. The dragon eventually falls in love with the elf.

The dragon and wizard travel to a village. There, the dragon works as a blacksmith I think. I believe the slayer squad come into the village and a fight goes on, but the village is saved due to the efforts of the dragon, wizard, and elf.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This question could use more detail; check out the [suggestions for good story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall anything else you can [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*A Dragon's Awakening* (2011) by Aya Knight, first book of the *Chronicles of Kale* series.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10419436-a-dragon-s-awakening):

> **Kale Firehart is a young dragon, and the sole survivor of his race.** As a tyrannical general and his massive bloodthirsty army close in on Kale—the most unexpected circumstance transpires. **With time against him, Kale's trusted friend, a veteran arcane sorcerer, transforms him into the one thing he despises most—a human.**
>
> Kale must unwillingly live among human-kind as he embarks upon an extraordinary journey. With a band of unlikely friends by his side, can Kale overcome the obstacles before him and return to the life he once knew?
>
> The age of dragons is all but over...

Various reviews mention an outcast female elf named Neelan.

---

Found with the Google query `fantasy book "last dragon" "turned * human" love elf site:goodreads.com/book`.

Comment: Thanks! That's the one!!